# Super weird Chrome/Safari css rendering bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, rendering

So I have a toggle button which toggles an 'expanded' class on an absolutely positioned element.  With the expanded class, the element gets set to have a bottom of 0px, without it, it has a bottom of -400px.

This exact setup works as expected before some changes I made, but now it doesn't.

Here's the weird part:
Everything works fine when adding the expanded class (the element moves up to bottom: 0px).  When I hit the toggle button to remove the class, the class gets removed and the correct css rules are in place (according to the chrome inspector's matched css rules), but the bottom isn't changing at all (it keeps being displayed as a 0px bottom even though the chrome inspector says it's -400px).

If I look at the computed styles for the element it shows the bottom as 0px (it should be -400px at this point), but when I open up the arrow next to it to see what's causing that, it shows it as -400px from the style sheet chrome thinks is being applied.

If I step through the function which removes the expanded class, it works as expected, but if I step over that function instead it doesn't (I know for a fact that function is still getting run, however).

Another very weird thing is the bottom will update to the correct state when certain hover-states of completely separate elements on the page are triggered (not every element's hover, just some of them).

This happens both in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox.

I thought this had to be a bug in Chrome, but given that this was working fine before the changes I made and that it's also reproducible in Safari, I feel like it has to be related to my code, but I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

The changes I made which seem to have broken this are a bunch of jQuery performance improvements, but since the code is working correctly (the class is getting toggled), I just have no idea what could be causing this.

Using Chrome 28.0.1500.71, Safari 6.0.3, Firefox 22.0 on a retina MacBook Pro running OS X 10.8.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please cut short your question to the point

Comment: Seemed to be a problem with the css transition I had on that element.  Still not sure what the hell was happening, but removing that transition (which wasn't touched at all in that commit) fixed it not updating correctly.